# How to efficiently update a large group of controls from a background thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Let's say you have a window with a bunch of property controls -- i.e., some text edit controls, date-time pickers, comboboxes, etc.  And then you have background worker thread for obtaining the data that will go into those controls.  And as the background thread obtains the necessary data for each control, it calls functions like `SetWindowText`, etc.

Will calling functions like `SetWindowText` defeat the purpose of getting the data asynchronously on a background thread?  In other words, will they make a lot of the activity synchronous?  Should any such functions be manually changed to a `PostMessage` calls?

Or are there any other ways to make updating the controls more efficient?  For example, would it likely make any difference to turn redraw off and then back on once all controls are set?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: use `PostMessage` to UI thread and update controls only from thread, which owner of windows

Comment: Is your window operational while some of its controls are not updated? I mean - can I type into an edit control when its content is suddenly updated?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I'm not sure I understand, but at least that's not the intended design.  The way it's intended to work is (1) the user selects a file whose properties they'd like to view, (2) those properties are displayed in the window's controls, (3) the user can edit the properties if desired, and then save.

Comment: @user15284017 in that case I would either not show the window until it is ready, or somehow disable all of its controls while everything is loaded. Then as @RbMM suggested, use `PostMessage`. I am not sure what "efficiency" are you concerned about. You *will* be able to keep reading while controls process those messages.

Comment: @RbMm Do you mean `PostMessage` with a custom message to update each control?

Comment: yes, of course custom, because not exist any standard